# League-wide retired numbers

Tags: trivia, history, international-sports, major-leagues

In honor of their great players, teams retire their numbers. But if that player has been one of the all time greats, then the league might consider retiring that number. As an example, Wayne Gretzky's number 99 has been retired across the NHL.

Is this the only example where a number is retired in an entire league? If not, please provide the player's name and number, as well as the teams he played for.

I'm looking for an answer for major leagues (i.e. MLB, NFL, NBA & NHL). But if there happens to be no retired numbers, then we can take a look at soccer leagues such as the EPL, LaLiga and Bundesliga.

Comment: How come North American sports are considered 'major' leagues compared to other Global sports ?

Comment: @queeg I live in Canada and here in North America we use the term "major leagues" to refer to the top 4 leagues (MLB, NFL, NBA & NHL) since they are the major professional league for Baseball, Football, Baseball and Hockey. Take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_professional_sports_leagues_in_the_United_States_and_Canada

Comment: Do we really need a `big4` tag? I understand they're considered the top 4 professional North American leagues, but that is the first time I ever heard it referred to as such. http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/352

Comment: That said, `international-sports` is intended to catch all sports, or specify that a multitude of sports is being asked about.

Comment: I tried to use tags for each of NFL, MLB, NBA and NHL, but you can only put 5 tags per question and having all the tags I had, I was over that limit. So I made a tag for big4.

Comment: That still doesn't justify its use, considering you're referring to more than just those four sports/professional leagues. It appears only [one question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfl+nhl+mlb+nba) on Sports SE is about the "big 4."

Comment: Well besides those leagues I only referred to soccer because I was doubting that there would be any answer for retired numbers in the leagues mentioned, and I follow soccer so it only made sense to check for credible soccer leagues.
I believe we will get more questions on MLB, NFL, NBA & NHL together since these leagues are so big in North America. And given that, it is almost impossible not to surpass the 5-tag limit, so we might need to invest in a tag for these 4 leagues. We can't really use international-sports, cause the leagues are only limited to the US and Canada.

Comment: maybe a change of names, from big4 to something more reasonable, like "major Leagues" or "North American Major Leagues" will do the trick

Comment: I understand the 5-tag limit, but the question is not specific to the big 4, nor is it specific to any one particular sport. Also, like the football-soccer dichotomy that exists between the US and other countries, there's contention with respect to singling out the top North American leagues compared to international leagues. And how do sports in US/Canada not have an international reach?  Let's continue any discussion in the linked meta question (see above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jackie Robinson's number 42 was retired by the MLB. Those wearing 42 were allowed to continue, but players couldn't switch to it and new players couldn't have it. Mariano Rivera was the last player to wear 42 in the MLB.

Robinson played for the Brooklyn Dodgers starting in 1947 and famously broke the color barrier in the MLB. He was a first ballot hall of famer.

The MLB retired his number in 1997 and currently all players wear 42 on "Jackie Robinson Day" (April 15th).

His number 42 was retired by UCLA in all sports on the 22nd November 2014. UCLA is where he went to college and lettered in 4 sports.